# Mongo DB Accumulators.sum within Accumulators.Push

Tags: java, mongodb

For starters I'm new to Mongo DB. Been following a few guides and examples such as those at 
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates

and 
http://zetcode.com/db/mongodbjava/

I've come to the conclusion that there are two ways of interacting with the database.  One using org.bson.Document and another using com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

I have solved my problem using the BasicDBObject but it doesnt look as clean and the logic gets more complex.

What i'm looking for here is how to convert what i have using BasicDBObjects into what uses Document.

Below is the contents of my List when using BasicDBObjects

```
[{{"$group": {"_id": {"site": "$site", "author": "$author"}, "AggCount": {"$sum": 1}}}, 
{"$sort": {"AggCount": -1}}, 
{"$group": {"_id": "$_id.site", "aggResults": {"$push": {"author": "$_id.author", "count": {"$sum": "$AggCount"}}}}}}]
```

When i execute the aggregate function on my collection my AggregateIterable Document contains the following which is what i want. I have two results grouped by site with the counts for each author at that site

```
Document{{_id=Dayton, aggResults=[Document{{author=jthomas, count=7}}, Document{{author=mculb, count=7}}, Document{{author=rjohn, count=4}}]}}
Document{{_id=Charleston, aggResults=[Document{{author=jree, count=9}}, Document{{author=cschm, count=6}}]}}
```

I believe i have the first group by and sort working with the Documents using the following.

```
bsonList.add(Aggregates.group(d, Accumulators.sum("aggCount", 1)));
bsonList.add(Aggregates.sort(Sorts.ascending("aggCount")));
```

which generates

```
[Stage{name='$group', id=Document{{site=$site, author=$author}}, fieldAccumulators=[BsonField{name='aggCount', value=Expression{name='$sum', expression=1}}]}, Stage{name='$sort', value={"aggCount": 1}}]
```

Where i think i'm stuck is on the push.  I currently have the following

```
for (String p : subAggFields) {
    subDoc.append(p, "$_id." + p);
  }

subDoc.append("count", Accumulators.sum("aggCount", 1));
bsonList.add(Aggregates.group(mainDoc, Accumulators.push("aggResults", subDoc)));
```

and including the above for the first group and sort i have

```
[Stage{name='$group', id=Document{{site=$site, author=$author}}, fieldAccumulators=[BsonField{name='aggCount', value=Expression{name='$sum', expression=1}}]}, 
Stage{name='$sort', value={"aggCount": 1}}, 
Stage{name='$group', id=Document{{_id=$site}}, fieldAccumulators=[BsonField{name='aggResults', value=Expression{name='$push', expression=Document{{author=$_id.author, count=BsonField{name='aggCount', value=Expression{name='$sum', expression=1}}}}}}]}]
```

I also know that the issue is with the following code because i get a org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.BsonField error.

```
count=BsonField{name='aggCount', value=Expression{name='$sum', expression=1}}
```

So in general i'm trying to figure out how to do accumulation.sum within the push.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the following way:

```
List<Bson> aggregates = Arrays.asList(
                Aggregates.group(Document.parse("{ 'site': '$site',  'author': '$author' }"),
                        Accumulators.sum("AggCount", 1)),
                Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending("AggCount")),
                Aggregates.group("$_id.site", Accumulators.push("aggResults", Document
                        .parse("{ 'author': '$_id.author',  'count': { '$sum': '$AggCount' } }"))));
```

Comment: While not in the format i was looking for it did point out the problem with the generation of my query.

Comment: What i was really looking for was for it to continue to follow the format in the example i outlined.  The following change is what i was looking for but if anyone can explain what the difference between the two is that would be great.  In my mind they are doing the same exact thing just written differently.  subDoc.append("count", Accumulators.sum("aggCount", 1));           to  subDoc.append("count", new Document("$sum", "$aggCount"));